# check if there is a div with a certain id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string and I need to check if there is in the page a div with id = to my string.

How can i do this with jquery?

Like:

```
if (isset $(mystring))
 // do somethinhg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($("#" + mystring).length > 0)
  alert(mystring + " exists!");
else
  alert("element with id " + mystring + " does not exist..");
```

Have this code either in the bottom of the page or wrapped inside `$(document).ready()` function otherwise even if the element exists further in the page it won't be recognized.

Comment: @yes yes indeed, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6hGzD/) live example. The `length` property apply to all jQuery objects and returns how many elements answer the filter/selector. In your case you just need to check for more than zero.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with:

```
if ( $('#' + mystring)[0] ) {
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is not needed to do this. In native js:

```
if (document.getElementById("mystring")) {
   alert("exists");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `is()` function.  http://api.jquery.com/is/

Here is a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/hRLgw/